# How to Shrink Raid 5 SAS to 3 Local Disks on windows server R2 2012?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, partition, raid5, sas

I've installed Windows server 2012R2 on HP ProLiant with 5 SAS Disks (300GBX5). after configuring Raid 5, the total visible size became 825 GB as Disk C. Is it alright?

if i want to create Disk D and E, is it possible using disk management on win Server 2012 or there is another way to avoid any problem?

Actually I want the best way to divide 825 GB into 3 disks.

Comment: Can you give the specific model and generation of your HP server?

Comment: @ewwhite HP ProLiant DL380 G9

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you have RAID5 there? RAID5 uses one parity drive thus, if you have 5x 300GB drives than you will have approximately 1.1TB of storage available.

It looks like RAID6 with two parity drives, and will give you near 800GB of storage.

If it's really RAID6 than I'd suggest you to rebuild it and make a clean fresh WinServer installation, so you can cut your storage to 3 disks during the installation. That's the easiest way to do that. Or you can use something like Acronis if you already have a big volume created.

Answer (score 1):

Do it over.

You can create multiple Logical Drives on the RAID controller.

Create one of the size you require for the OS... like 120GB. Then create additional for your data drives. D and E.

This is easy and available in the [HP Smart Storage Administrator](http://h20566.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=c03909334) (press F10 for "Intelligent Provisioning" during the system's POST).

While there is a "shrink size" option for your controller and Logical Drives, it's better to just do this the right way and reinstall.